# How to rebase only specific commits?

Tags: git, git-rebase

When I do `git rebase -i <commit>` it pulls up a list of commits starting from that commit and I have to choose which commits I want to edit by changing `pick` to `e`. But when I change `pick` to `e` and close out the editor git still iterates through all the commits and not just the ones I want to edit.

For example, I do `git rebase -i --root` and only choose to edit the latest commit made. Git still tries to iterate through the entire list of commits. After I close out the editor it says `Rebasing (1/593)` where 593 is the number of commits in the list. It goes through all 593 them.  It only stops to let me edit the ones I chose.

Is there a way to target only a specific commit, even if it's in between a lot of other commits, without having `rebase` go through the entire list?

Comment: What exactly do you mean _"still iterates through"_?

Comment: @jonrsharpe After I close out the editor it says `Rebasing (1/593)` where `593` is the number of commits in the list. It goes through all 593 them.

Comment: If you're editing some of the commits, any children of those commits now also have to be rewritten with the new parent, if that's what you mean. It's not entirely clear what your situation is.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I just want to edit only a single commit. I thought rebasing was how you do that.

Comment: It is. But changing a commit has implications for other commits that were based on the pre-edit version. _"It only stops to let me edit the ones I choose"_ - was that unexpected? It sounds like it's doing exactly what it's supposed to.

Comment: @jonrsharpe How do I edit the commit message of just one commit?

Comment: That _is_ how. But then all subsequent commits need to be rewritten to reflect the new parent. If you mean _without_ changing any other commit, then: unless it's the most recent commit, you can't.

Comment: BTW if you just want to change the commit message you can use `reword` instead of `edit`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The way to understand this is to understand what Git *is*. Git follows some extremely basic and important rules. Here are two of them:

1. No commit can ever be changed.
2. The parent pointer of a commit is part of that commit (and therefore, in accordance with rule 1, cannot be changed).

So now consider this situation:

```
A -- B -- C -- D (mybranch)
```

where time flows from left to right: A was created first, and is the parent of B, which is parent of C, which is parent of D.

Now let's say I want to change the commit message of A. Well, I can't! You can't change anything about a commit. But what you *can* do is *replace* A with a *different* commit — one that has a different commit message (but contains the same files).

But if you do that, you have this:

```
A -- B -- C -- D (mybranch)

A'
```

where A' is the new commit that is like A, but differs in its commit message. This is no good, because it isn't what we wanted. We want the history to stay "the same", with A' as the parent of B in the history. Well, we can't do that! You can't change the parentage of B. But what you *can* do is *replace* B with a *new* commit that *looks* like B but has A' as its parent:

```
A -- B -- C -- D (mybranch)

A' -- B'
```

But wait, there's more! We have to keep doing that, *for all the subsequent commits*. And when we get done, Git simply moves the `mybranch` pointer to the new history:

```
A -- B -- C -- D

A' -- B' -- C' -- D' (mybranch)
```

*That* is what happens when you use interactive rebase to edit the commit message of A. You get *all new commits* for A *and all the commits after it*.

And that is exactly what you are seeing and asking about.

---

To see that this is true, try it on an example repo, and *watch the SHA numbers*. Here's an example. I use `git log` to see what I have at the start:

```
* 0c32c25 (HEAD -> main) d
* 12ec6ca c
* 28b1e17 b
* b8cb561 a
```

Now I interactive rebase down to the root; here's how I edit the todo list:

```
r b8cb561 a
pick 28b1e17 b
pick 12ec6ca c
pick 0c32c25 d
```

I reword the first commit so that its message is `a with a different commit message`. Now the rebase finishes, and this is what I get:

```
* 0931c89 (HEAD -> main) d
* 45ebf0a c
* 084b06c b
* bcc0bed a with a different commit message
```

Look at the SHA numbers. *They have all changed*. That's because these are *not the same commits I started with!* They have all been replaced.

---

One final observation. If you're watching carefully, you should be saying: In the diagram, what happens to the *original* A thru D that have been "replaced"?

```
A -- B -- C -- D

A' -- B' -- C' -- D' (mybranch)
```

It looks like they are *still there*. Yes, you're right! They *are* still there. After your big rebase, all your commits are *duplicated*. The new versions exist, and *so do the old versions*. This is actually a really cool feature of Git: commits are *not erased* when they are replaced.

In this particular situation, you have no easy way to access the original A thru D. But you could if you wanted to. For example, you could use the reflog. Or you could have put another branch name on D before doing the rebase.

Eventually, the repo will be "garbage collected". Git will notice that *no branch name* points to D, and therefore to C, B, and A. They are considered "unreachable", and Git *will* delete them. But it could be *weeks* before that happens. You have lots of time to recover the originals if that's what you want to do. Cool, eh?

Answer (score 2):

##### How to rebase only specific commits

Be as narrow as you can in your call to edit the history:

- if you want to edit the most recent commit, use `git commit --amend`
- if you want to edit the fourth commit from the most recent, use `git rebase -i HEAD~4`
- if the history is long enough that you don't want to count, find the sha1 of the commit just before the one you want to modify, and use `git commit -i <sha1>`
- in all cases, make sure you don't rebase over a merge point unless you know what you're doing (see below for why).

##### Why it's important to be narrow

A blind `git rebase -i --root` operation is actually a dangerous thing to do.

Innocuous issue, **performance**: if you ask rebase to recreate all the commits identically, it will take the commits one by one and recreate each of them, but since the result is identical it's a noop, you've just recreated the exact same commits, only wasting your and your machine's time doing it. This is what you're observing with that (1/593).

Dangerous issue, **destroying merges**: if your history has any merges in it, rebasing over them will actually skip them by default, replacing the original history with a linear history that has the same code (I believe) but is now disconnected from the original history starting at the first merge that got skipped. You can use `git rebase -i --rebase-merges --root` instead, but why would you do all that work for nothing?